# 'Server' object has no attribute 'view'

Tags: python, couchdb

I get this error when I try to list all documents returned by one of my views. The view itself is called `user`. When I access it through curl like:

```
curl .../_view/user
```

Then I get a whole bunch of documents. If, however, I try to do it from python, following this [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html), I get an error message: `'Server' object has no attribute 'view'`. I do it like this:

```
>>> import couchdb
>>> db = couchdb.Server('http://127.0.0.1:5984/reestr')
>>> for r in db.view('user'):
...    print(r)

'Server' object has no attribute 'view'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: there is no method as view in the server method what are you trying to do and what is your end result

Comment: I'm trying to get the same results in Python code, as I get through curl. `curl .../_view/user` returns me documents corresponding to map function `user`. How can I do the same thing in Python. Besides, you say, that there is no such a method. But what does db.view mean in documentation?

Comment: And, by the way, I do like DRY and I do not want to write a new temporary map function in Python code. What I want is to use the existing map function (in my case it is called `user`). I gues this is the most trivial thing in the world, that a programmer needs from CouchDb. "Ok, I have a view. I tested it with curl, it returns data. But what if I want to use this view in Python code?"

Answer (score 0):

```
import couchdb
server = Server()
db = server['reestr']
for r in db.view('user'):
  print()
  ...
```

https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html